# 3D Cone Plot using TikZ over scatteplot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want  to draw a 3D cone over some particular point of the scatterplot. So the picture will look like below:

[image]

I have looked into the pgfplot documentation for 3D cone drawing but could not find much. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking the code from [Tom's answer for your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/275649/11232), this may be a starting point:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{s.dat}
x   y   m
1   2   3
2   1   4
1   1   2
2   2   1
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[   view={120}{40},
    xmin=0,xmax=3,
    ymin=0,ymax=3,
    zmin=0, zmax=5,
]
    \addplot3[only marks, ycomb, scatter, mark=cube*, mark size=3,
        point meta=explicit, z filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{0}\pgfmathresult},
] table[meta=m] {s.dat};
    \addplot3[mark=none, ycomb] table {s.dat};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
hide axis,
domain=0:1,
y domain=0:-2*pi,
xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5,
ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5, zmin=-1.2,
samples=10,
samples y=40,
z buffer=sort,
]
\addplot3[mesh]
({1.1*x*cos(deg(y))},{1.1*x*sin(deg(y))},{-x});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With only scatter plot:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{s.dat}
x   y   m
1   2   3
2   1   4
1   1   2
2   2   1
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[   view={120}{40},
    xmin=0,xmax=3,
    ymin=0,ymax=3,
    zmin=0, zmax=5,
]
    \addplot3[only marks, scatter, mark=*, mark size=3,
        point meta=explicit, z filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{0}\pgfmathresult},
] table[meta=m] {s.dat};    
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
hide axis,
domain=0:1,
y domain=0:-2*pi,
xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5,
ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5, zmin=-1.2,
samples=10,
samples y=40,
z buffer=sort,
]
\addplot3[mesh,olive]
({1.1*x*cos(deg(y))},{1.1*x*sin(deg(y))},{-x});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]