# Drawing vertical Bars in a 3D plot

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I am new to Latex, and I am trying to plot train of pulses of two variables, something like:

z = A * delta(x-x_0) * delta(y - y_0)

The best I can get at the moment is just a single mark where I would like to have at least a thin bar representing the delta. My data are in a .txt file. The first two columns represent the position for which the Dirac deltas are non-null, while the third column represent the amplitude of the Dirac delta in the specified position.

This is the image I get:

[image]

This is my code:

```
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[view={-75}{25}, %axis equal,
xlabel={$\bar{\alpha}/\omega_0$}, 
ylabel={$\omega / \omega_0$},
zlabel={$\lvert S_{\Psi} \rvert [mWb]$},
zlabel style={rotate=-90},

axis background/.style={fill=white},
xmajorgrids=true,
ymajorgrids=true,
zmajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,]
\addplot3
[only marks, mark size=0.5, color = blue]
table[]{./img/cyclic_spectra_239.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I always thought that Dirac deltas were infinite. In any case, you'd need to provide some data file and a full document that makes your code run though.

Comment: ... and I guess you will get what you want by adding `ycomb` to your options, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275668/121799). That is, use `\addplot3
[ycomb,only marks, mark size=0.5, color = blue]
table[]{./img/cyclic_spectra_239.txt};`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, and sorry for the poor definition of the problem, Dirac deltas are infinite of course :D Anyway "ycomb" was the graphical tool I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I guess that there are two options. Either this question will be identified as a duplicate or my above comment to use

```
\addplot3 [ycomb,only marks, mark size=0.5, color = blue] table[]{./img/cyclic_spectra_239.txt};
```

could serve as an answer. This comment is based on this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275668/121799), from which I learned that `ycomb` does what one expects a currently unavailable `zcomb` what do. I am posting this because the title of the corresponding question does not necessarily suggest that the answer can be found there.