# pgfplot: add lines from points to x axis

Tags: pgfplots, automation

I am a beginner with pgfplot and latex automation in general. I am drawing a 3d scatter plot, as shown in the attached Figure. I would like to draw a line from each points to the bottom surface (so z = 0, and x and y would be the points coordinates). 
These points come from a CSV file. Is there a way to do what I want without plotting every lines manually? 
Thanks a lot for your help.

edit: Here is my code, sorry for the missing.

```latex
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel = x ylabel = y, zlabel = z, title=test, grid=major, grid style = {dashed, gray!30}, ymin=0, ymax=1, ylabel style={rotate=90}]
    \addplot3+[only marks] table[col sep=comma] {Results_CSV/F6/data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here are some points:

```
54,0.025,0.025
39,0.05,0.05
34,0.075,0.075
32,0.1,0.1
32,0.125,0.125
```

Where first, second and third rows are x, y and z axis respectively.

[image: example]

Comment: As always it helps to produce your code structure so others can help to add the z vectors in the correct relative part of your code, keep it simple just a handful of points are enough plus your file outline preamble starting with \documentclass   (just enough to plot the graph above)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I have added the code and some points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! It has been pointed out [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275668/121799) that `ycomb` works here. Full credits go to Tom Bombadil. The plane is just to guide the eye.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
54,0.025,0.025
39,0.05,0.05
34,0.075,0.075
32,0.1,0.1
32,0.125,0.125
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel = $x$,ylabel = $y$, zlabel = $z$, title=test, grid=major, 
    grid style = {dashed, gray!30}, enlargelimits=0.2, 
    ylabel style={rotate=90}]
    \fill[red,opacity=0.3]  
     (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin},0) 
     -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin},0) 
     -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax},0)
     -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax},0) -- cycle;
    \addplot3+[ycomb] table[col sep=comma,header=false] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working very well! Do you know how to change the color of ycomb?

Comment: @JeanOudot The colors used in`\addplot3+` are determined by the cycle list. If you add `\pgfplotsset{cycle list={{red, mark=*}}}`, say, the plot will become red. This is described in section **4.7.7 Cycle Lists – Options Controlling Line Styles** of the pgfplots manual.